# Makefile compiling and linking problems

Tags: c

So I've been trying to search for a solution that Im having with my make file currently. I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
```

So I have 5 files in my src folder: find.c, rebalance.c, remove.c, lib.c, and insert.c. In my src/bin folder I just have main.c and in another folder 'include' outside of src I have bst.h. This is what my makefile looks like:

```
all: static bin shared
    mkdir -p build/bin
    mkdir -p build/lib
    mkdir -p build/objects
    mv *.o build/objects
    mv *.a build/lib
    mv main build/bin
    mv libbst.so build/lib

static: 
    gcc src/lib.c -c -I include
    gcc src/find.c -c -I include
    gcc src/insert.c -c -I include
    gcc src/rebalance.c -c -I include
    gcc src/remove.c -c -I include
    ar rcs libbst.a find.o insert.o lib.o rebalance.o remove.o

shared: 
    gcc -c -o lib.o src/lib.c
    gcc -c -o find.o src/find.c
    gcc -c -o insert.o src/insert.c
    gcc -c -o rebalance.o src/rebalance.c
    gcc -c -o remove.o src/remove.c
    gcc -shared -o libbst.so find.o insert.o lib.o rebalance.o remove.o

bin:
    gcc src/lib.c -c -I include
    gcc lib.o -o lib -lbst -L.
    gcc src/bin/main.c -c -I include
    gcc main.o -o main -lbst -L.

clean:
    rm -rf *.so *.a *.o main build

install:
```

Im assuming that I'm just not using the right commands to link everything together. This always fails in the 'bin' section of the Makefile. I would really appreciate any help or advice on what I can do here, im kind of stumped right now.

Comment: If you run `make VERBOSE=1`, it'd be easier to see the full command and figure out the problem easily.

Comment: Do you have a [main](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html)?

Comment: Please show your full build log.

Comment: `gcc lib.o -o lib -lbst -L.` That looks wrong. It will try to link an executable but I'm guessing `lib.c` is not an actual main program but rather a library. So you can't link it as an executable.

Comment: Regardless of what the problem ends up being it should be noted that this is not a good Makefile. A good Makefile would not have explicit build commands for every single source file. Instead, general rules are provided such as "how to build a .o from a .c" and then every C file would match and use that rule.

Comment: @Neil what do you mean by build log? Also if your asking if I have a main method then yeah its in my main.c program.

Comment: It might help if you described more in detail the context of your project.